# Why is the number of surjective functions from an $n$-element set to a $k$-element set not given by $n^k$?

Tags: combinatorics

The following screenshot shows a lemma & proof from my combinatorics lecture notes

[image: notes]

However, I am struggling to understand this result. Surely, since a surjective function is one for which every element in the range is mapped onto, every possible surjective function arises by choosing an element in the range and then choosing an element in the domain to be mapped on to it.

For example, if our domain is
$$
A : = \{ a_1, \dots, a_n \}
$$
and our range is
$$
B := \{ b_1, \dots, b_k \}
$$
then every surjective mapping arises by choosing, for each $b_i \in B$, some $a_j \in A$ such that $b_i = f(a_j)$. Clearly, since there are $n$ elements in our range, there are $n$ ways to choose such a value of $a_j$. Thus, since we must do this $k$ times, the total number of possibilities would be $n^k$ by the multiplication principle.

Clearly my reasoning is not correct, but I am unsure as to why. Can someone help me to understand the flaw in my logic?

Comment: Well, try $n=2,k=1$.

Comment: The problem is that your method badly overcounts.  If $a,b$ both map to $A$ then you incorrectly count the choice of $a$ and the choice of $b$ (all else fixed) as giving two different functions.

Comment: Yes, I find that in counting problems sometimes explicitly writing out an example of the set and counting the elements by hand can be more useful than spending a long time thinking about it abstractly, especially when just starting out.

Comment: It also counts things that are not even possibilities -- such as the same element of $A$ mapping to _all_ the elements of $B$.

Comment: Even when one is _not_ just starting out, @JairTaylor's suggestion is a useful sanity check that it's foolish to omit if one needed to think _at all_ about how to count things. Just verifying with a single example of size 2 or 3 will catch a large fraction of fencepost errors.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed, and it's also very useful to verify formulae using a computer to do a brute-force count. These kind of checks let you directly think about the question "How do I count this?" instead of the question "Why is the author of this book doing it this way?" that I often see.

Comment: What is denoted $S_{n,k}$? B.t.w., your error is this: once you've chosen an $a_j$ to be mapped onto a $b_i$, it is no more available to be mapped onto another $b_{i'}$. So you can't simply multiply the possibilities for each $b_i$.

Comment: @Bernard They are the [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: @JairTaylor: Oh! yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are two flaws in your logic.
First is that, there may be more than one pre-image for a chosen $b_i$ from $B$. If there are $t$ pre-images of $b_i$ then this can be chosen from $A$ by ${n\choose t}$ ways, but you have taken $n={n\choose 1}$, that is, you have taken only one pre-image. But that's not sufficient(in case more than one pre-image)
Second is that, If you take some particular preimage of $b_i$, from $A$, this can be done in ${n\choose 1}=n$ ways, but after choosing that , a second pre-image of a different $b_j$ can be chosen by ${n-1\choose 1}$ ways, and so on.(You have chosen all preimages in $n$ ways, which is not the case)

Now for the clarification of the given result, $S(n,k)$ is Stirling's number of second kind which is defined by "all possible ways to partition a $n$ element set in $k$ parts".Now for $|A|=n, |B|=k$ ,if $f:A\to B$ is a onto map then the preimage make $k$ partition of $A$. Now there are $S(n,k)$ $k$-partition of $A$ and for each partition, there are $k!$ surjective maps. So the, total number of surjective map is, $k!S(n,k)$.